# How to select elements in the DB depending on a boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am running a Ruby On Rails 6.0.3.1 server with a SQLite3 database.

One of my models is called `Airport` and has several colums like `listable` which is a boolean.

I want to call `Airport.listable` to get all the airports that should be displayed in the list.

```
// app/models/airport.rb
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :icao, :latitude, :longitude, presence: true
    validates :icao, uniqueness: true

    has_many :departure_compagny_routes, class_name: 'CompagnyRoute', foreign_key: 'departure_id'
    has_many :arrival_compagny_routes, class_name: 'CompagnyRoute', foreign_key: 'arrival_id'

    scope :listable, -> { where(listable: true) }

    def to_param
        icao
    end

    def compagny_routes
        departure_compagny_routes + arrival_compagny_routes
    end
end
```

When I call `Airport.listable`, I get an empty list. I get the same problem when calling `Airport.where(listable: true)`.

I recently updated my application from Rails 4.2 to Rails 6, and the code worked perfectly until then.

I have the very same problem with other models: `Model.where(boolean_attribute: bool)` is always empty, but calling `Airport.where(iata: nil)`, where `iata` is a string, works perfectly.

How can I get rid of this and have my scope work?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```rb
scope :listable, -> { where(listable: 1) }
```

SQLite might be getting confused because it doesn't have real booleans.

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that might be the issue. Your `scope` syntax looks correct. I don't think that is the issue. It's strange that you do get results with `.select{ |a| a.listable? }` but maybe there is a clue in that. I'll keep thinking about it. Hopefully someone has an answer because I'm genuinely curious.